# How to delete folder after MediaElement in WPF play file

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I am testing `MediaElement` in `WPF`.

but frequently `Directory.Delete` function show error.

I don't know Why the error occurs.

```
  MediaElement mediatest = new MediaElement();
  mediatest.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
  root.Children.Add(mediatest);

mediatest.BeginInit();
mediatest.Source = null;
mediatest.Source = new Uri(MediaSrc);
mediatest.EndInit();.
mediatest.Play();

stop()
mediatest.Stop();
mediatest.Close();             
mediatest.Source = null;            
mediatest = null;
root.Children.Clear();
System.IO.Directory.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"sound"), true);
```

Comment: What kind of exception you get?

Comment: it is "System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty." but when I finded the folder, where was no file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instead of `Directory.Delete` the following method:

```
public static void DeleteDirectory(string target_dir)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(target_dir);
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(target_dir);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        DeleteDirectory(dir);
    }

    Directory.Delete(target_dir, false);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the same issue appear. and I am trying to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, but the same issue appear. and I am trying to check it.

```
mediatest.Stop();
mediatest.Close();             
mediatest.Source = null;            
mediatest = null;
root.Children.Clear();
GC.Collect();
```

but the same issue appear again.
and then I changed source following

```
GC.Collect(); 
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

now I didn't see an error so far.